# Is it possible to return the cursor to nth previous line?

Tags: java, console-application

I want to print the pattern:

```
  *     
  *   * 
  *   * *
* *   * *
* * * * *
```

the code must print the number of `*` in a column with respect to the given inputs.

In this example the input provided is `{2,5,1,4,3}`.

Comment: No it's not possible

Comment: Is there any way to do it using multi-dimensional array?

Comment: It's possible with [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) if your terminal supports it. This should work on most Linux and Mac terminal emulators, but not in Windows CMD. I'm not sure if the consoles in IDEs support them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java bar chart method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419009/java-bar-chart-method)

Comment: What OS and what editor are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter what OS or editor - the tag specifies it is a console app.

Comment: @Jason Editor usually doesn't matter, but I've seen some Comp Sci graders run the submissions in a terminal within the IDE. OS matters because the Windows console doesn't support ANSI codes.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused as to why we need ansi codes? The character is `shift-8`.

Comment: Oh, I see - if you are trying to output the characters by moving the cursor position upwards on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void printStars(final int[] inputArray) {

    // get the maximum value from the array
    int max = 0;
    for(final int value : inputArray) {
        if(value > max) {
            max = value;
        }
    }

    for(int row = max; row >= 1; row--) {
        for(final int value : inputArray) {
            if(value >= row) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: using windows OS and notepad